# C++20: Concepts of multiple types and its constraint, correct syntax?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

It is confirmed that in the upcoming `c++20` standard, according to [this reddit report](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/cfk9de/201907_cologne_iso_c_committee_trip_report_the/) from the recent [Cologne ISO C++ Meeting](https://isocpp.org/std/meetings-and-participation/upcoming-meetings), we will be able to specify a template's [**concept**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B)) and for each class/function template, we will be able to set the [**constraints**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) on its types. However, in documentations and tutorials (e.g. [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints)), I could not find the correct syntax for the multi-type use-case.

---

Suppose we have a multi-type concept:

```cpp
template<typename T1, typename T2>
concept AreEqComparable = requires(T1 a, T2 b) {
    { a == b } -> bool;
};
```

Let's say, I want to define a simple comparison function between two different types. **How can I do that?** More specifically, what should I write in the `???` part of the code below:

```cpp
???
bool are_equal(T1 a, T2 b) { return a == b; }
```

I couldn't find any reference to this case in [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints), [here](https://cppdepend.com/blog/?p=524), and even [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B)). I have randomly tried something like:

```
/* 1 */ template<AreEqComparable T1, T2>
/* 2 */ AreEqComparable<T1, T2>
/* 3 */ template<AreEqComparable<T1, T2>>
```

But all of them throw syntax errors. I think the answer should lie somewhere in the specification [P0557](http://www.stroustrup.com/good_concepts.pdf) by [Bjarne Stroustrup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup), but I wasn't able to find it after a quick look.

Comment: I have not used concepts but did you try `template<AreEqComparable T1, AreEqComparable T2>`? Also `IsEqComparable ` may be a better name (because it only applies to one parameter).

Comment: @Galik Tried that just now, doesn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
    requires AreEqComparable<T1, T2>
bool are_equal(T1 a, T2 b)
{
    // ...
}
```

Here, we use a *requires-clause* to impose a requirement on the type template parameters.

Comment: Thanks, that works (I'm using online compiler [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/)). Are there more compact ways to write it? I mean in the `template` clause, without having to explicitly specify `requires ...`?

Comment: @FalconUA We can write `template <typename T1, AreEqComparable<T1> T2>`, but that is subtly different - it is actually `AreEqComparable<T2, T1>`.  I am not really aware of a more compact version.

Comment: @FalconUA, The TS originally had `AreEqComparable{T1, T2} bool are_equal(…);`, but no equivalent shorthand made it into C++20.

Answer (score 15):

You can write:

```
template <typename T1, AreEqComparable<T1> T2>
bool are_equal(T1, T2);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
    requires AreEqComparable<T2, T1>
bool are_equal(T1, T2);
```

The types are flipped in the constraint here, `AreEqComparable<T2, T1>` instead of `AreEqComparable<T1, T2>`. This will certainly matter for many concepts, but probably not this one in particular since `==` itself becomes symmetric in C++20 (short of pathological cases which should not exist in real code). And if you want to be *really* sure that this symmetry is valid, you can always make it explicit in the concept (as [`EqualityComparableWith`](http://eel.is/c++draft/concept.equalitycomparable) is in the working draft):

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
concept AreEqComparable = requires(T1 a, T2 b) {
    { a == b } -> bool;
    { b == a } -> bool;
};
```

---

You can actually get the constraint you want in the correct order by flipping the order of the template parameters (h/t Matthieu M.):

```
template <typename T2, AreEqComparable<T2> T1>
bool are_equal(T1, T2);
```

Comment: `template <typename T1, AreEqComparable<T1> T2>` is this really the correct syntax? It looks kinda off  :O I was expecting something like `template <typename T1, AreEqComparable<T1, T2>>`

Comment: @ruohola Yes, it's correct. We're introducing the type `T2` with the partial-concept-id `AreEqComparable<T1>`. I don't know how the other syntax would introduce `T2`.

Comment: Why not write `template <typename T2, AreEqComparable<T2> T1> bool are_equal(T1, T2)` then? You'd get the arguments in the right order...

Comment: @MatthieuM. Oh, yeah. You can do that.

Comment: Thanks for in-depth explanation!

Answer (score 6):

Yet another syntax that avoids introducing template parameters at all (at the cost of adding other redundancy):

```
bool are_equal(auto x,auto y)
  requires AreEqComparable<decltype(x),decltype(y)>
  {return x==y;}
```

Comment: Wow, is there any rule of where one can put the `requires` statement?

Comment: @FalconUA: After `template<…>`or after `R f(…)`—only for functions in the latter case, of course, which need not even be templates (they could be members of a class template, for instance).

Comment: Fun fact, if you use `class` and name the parameters `X`, and `Y`, this is a full two characters shorter than a normal template declaration :-) (82 vs 84)

Comment: @Barry: Sounds like I need a macro for `decltype` to keep ahead.

Comment: @DavisHerring oh, I meant, the `decltype` version is 2 chars shorter.

Comment: @Barry: Of course—but the other might be improved somehow, so I need insurance!

Comment: Can concepts be used with special member functions?  I mean, you cannot templatize a copy constructor, for example.

Comment: @L.F.: Yes; even destructors can be constrained, and you can have more than one such *prospective* destructor.

Answer (score 3):

In GCC 8.2.0, concepts should be written like:

```
concept bool ConceptName = /* ... */
```

But [C++ Templates: The Complete Guide](http://www.tmplbook.com/) doesn't mention the `bool`. Since the C++20 standard is not released, it's hard to say which is right.

For concepts that need one parameter (not necessarily type), there's a shorthand:

```
template <UnaryConceptName T>
```

For those that need two or more parameters, there's no shorthand:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> requires BinaryConceptName<T1, T2>
```

`typename` can be replaced with specific type name.

By the way:

1. The book I mentioned above gives a brief introduction to concepts.
2. use `-fconcepts` in GCC to enable concepts.

Comment: `concept bool` was the syntax in the Concepts TS. C++20 will be just `concept`.